# How to import a library directly from master branch in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-redux, react-router

https://github.com/danielcaldas/react-d3-graph/issues/276

The question is related to above issue. I tried to update webpack as mentioned in the answers on github but i am constantly getting the same error. I am using create-react-app and typescript.

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (127:33)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|      * @returns {Object} - Focus and zoom animation properties.
|      */
>     _generateFocusAnimationProps = () => {
|         const { focusedNodeId } = this.state;
```

I also tried installing it directly via npm but it is not working and I am getting the same error.

Tried importing like

```
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph/src/index";
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph/src";
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph";
```

does not work so I am pretty much sure that the issue is with web pack any help is appreciated.

**Webpack**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const safePostCssParser = require('postcss-safe-parser');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const paths = require('./paths');
const modules = require('./modules');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');

const postcssNormalize = require('postcss-normalize');
const appPackageJson = require(paths.appPackageJson);
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';

const imageInlineSizeLimit = parseInt(
  process.env.IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT || '10000'
);
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';
  const isEnvProductionProfile =
    isEnvProduction && process.argv.includes('--profile');


  const publicPath = isEnvProduction
    ? paths.servedPath
    : isEnvDevelopment && '/';
  const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';

  const publicUrl = isEnvProduction
    ? publicPath.slice(0, -1)
    : isEnvDevelopment && '';
  const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: '../../' } : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
        // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
        // package.json
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 3,
            }),


            postcssNormalize(),
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push(
        {
          loader: require.resolve('resolve-url-loader'),
          options: {
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    // Stop compilation early in production
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    // These are the "entry points" to our application.
    // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
    entry: [
      // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
      // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
      // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
      // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
      // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
      // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
      // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
      // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
      // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
      // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
      // Finally, this is your app's code:
      paths.appIndexJs,
      "./index.jsx"
      // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
      // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
      // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
    ].filter(Boolean),
    output: {
      // The build folder.
      path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,
      // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
      // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
      // In development, it does not produce real files.
      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      // TODO: remove this when upgrading to webpack 5
      futureEmitAssets: true,
      // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
      // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
      // We use "/" in development.
      publicPath: publicPath,
      // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? info =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')),
      // Prevents conflicts when multiple Webpack runtimes (from different apps)
      // are used on the same page.
      jsonpFunction: `webpackJsonp${appPackageJson.name}`,
      // this defaults to 'window', but by setting it to 'this' then
      // module chunks which are built will work in web workers as well.
      globalObject: 'this',
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        // This is only used in production mode
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {

              ecma: 8,
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,

            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true,
            },
            // Added for profiling in devtools
            keep_classnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            keep_fnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,
              // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
              ascii_only: true,
            },
          },
          sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
        }),
        // This is only used in production mode
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {
            parser: safePostCssParser,
            map: shouldUseSourceMap
              ? {
                  // `inline: false` forces the sourcemap to be output into a
                  // separate file
                  inline: false,
                  // `annotation: true` appends the sourceMappingURL to the end of
                  // the css file, helping the browser find the sourcemap
                  annotation: true,
                }
              : false,
          },
        }),
      ],

      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        name: false,
      },

      runtimeChunk: {
        name: entrypoint => `runtime-${entrypoint.name}`,
      },
    },
    resolve: {

      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),

      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {

        'react-native': 'react-native-web',

        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      plugins: [

        // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
        // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
        // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
        // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
      ],
    },
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [
        // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells Webpack to load its loaders
        // from the current package.
        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [

        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
      },
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        {
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                cache: true,
                formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
                resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,

              },
              loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
            },
          ],
          include: paths.appSrc,
        },
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),

                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent:
                            '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,

                // Babel sourcemaps are needed for debugging into node_modules
                // code.  Without the options below, debuggers like VSCode
                // show incorrect code and set breakpoints on the wrong lines.
                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: {
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
              }),
            },
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: {
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true,
                },
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),
      // Inlines the webpack runtime script. This script is too small to warrant
      // a network request.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5358
      isEnvProduction &&
        shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
        new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime-.+[.]js/]),
      // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
      // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
      // <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
      // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
      // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
      // In development, this will be an empty string.
      new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
      // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
      // the requesting resource.
      new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
      // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
      // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
      // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV is set to production
      // during a production build.
      // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),

      isEnvDevelopment && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

      isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),

      isEnvDevelopment &&
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
      isEnvProduction &&
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
          // both options are optional
          filename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
          chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
        }),
      // Generate an asset manifest file with the following content:
      // - "files" key: Mapping of all asset filenames to their corresponding
      //   output file so that tools can pick it up without having to parse
      //   `index.html`
      // - "entrypoints" key: Array of files which are included in `index.html`,
      //   can be used to reconstruct the HTML if necessary
      new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
        publicPath: publicPath,
        generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
          const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
            manifest[file.name] = file.path;
            return manifest;
          }, seed);
          const entrypointFiles = entrypoints.main.filter(
            fileName => !fileName.endsWith('.map')
          );

          return {
            files: manifestFiles,
            entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
          };
        },
      }),

      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),

      isEnvProduction &&
        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
          clientsClaim: true,
          exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
          importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn',
          navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
          navigateFallbackBlacklist: [

            new RegExp('^/_'),

            new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$'),
          ],
        }),

      useTypeScript &&
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
          typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
            basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
          }),
          async: isEnvDevelopment,
          useTypescriptIncrementalApi: true,
          checkSyntacticErrors: true,
          resolveModuleNameModule: process.versions.pnp
            ? `${__dirname}/pnpTs.js`
            : undefined,
          resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveModule: process.versions.pnp
            ? `${__dirname}/pnpTs.js`
            : undefined,
          tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
          reportFiles: [
            '**',
            '!**/__tests__/**',
            '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
            '!**/src/setupProxy.*',
            '!**/src/setupTests.*',
          ],
          silent: true,
          // The formatter is invoked directly in WebpackDevServerUtils during development
          formatter: isEnvProduction ? typescriptFormatter : undefined,
        }),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    node: {
      module: 'empty',
      dgram: 'empty',
      dns: 'mock',
      fs: 'empty',
      http2: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      child_process: 'empty',
    },
    performance: false,
  };
};
```

Comment: Did you try to download the github repo, build it locally and then `npm link` it? I'm suspecting you're requiring the exact source code, "un-transpiled", at the moment.

Comment: no i didnt try that because i was not aware of it

Comment: I'll write an answer which elaborates on my comment then.

Comment: this worked thanks :) though still waiting for your answer now even i can write it but i have a question so if i change system do i have to again and again clone the main repo since this library is still present locally i would really like to have a remote solution too so that i dont need to clone the repo over and over

Comment: I can't think of any remote solution. This kind of a workflow is only suggested in dev environments where you're trying to test something which is not released yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184789/how-to-import-a-library-directly-from-master-branch-in-react?noredirect=1#comment106451735_60184789). You could do this

1. Clone the repo to your local file system.
2. Run the repo's build commands to generate a build. You'll need to see the building instructions from the repo itself. Usually available in README.md or CONTRIBUTING.md.
3. Then, use either use `npm link` or `npm install` to reference the locally built package.

Comment: i think you should update your answer it is a two step process you need to first build then go to build dir and type npm link and then go to the project you need to import to and then type npm link projectname